# Creating Customer Attribute in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-attribute, custom-attributes

I want to create three custom attribute for customer like(child name, DOB, Gender) how do i do that in magento 1.9.2.2. I tried to create it using SQL file it is created in database, but it was not coming on registration page.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to create customer attribute install [extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-attributes.html)

You can create customer attribute from admin **Customers > manage attributes**